# How can I drag windows on Openbox without title bar?

Tags: mouse, openbox, window-management

I removed the title bar from Openbox by modifying the `/openbox/rc.xml`. I know that I can use keybindings to minimize, maximize, close, etc. But, how can I drag the windows with the mouse like I did before?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to this Ubuntu forums post, add the following to your rc.xml file:

> [Re: window dragging in openbox](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=811194&p=5070326#post5070326)
>
> I think you would want to change (or add) a mousebind entry to the Mouse section of rc.xml with a different binding. Mine currently says this:
>
> ```
> <mousebind button="A-Left" action="Drag">
> <action name="Move"/>
> </mousebind>
> ```

Then you can move windows by dragging them while pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>. To use the <kbd>Super</kbd>-drag instead use `button="W-Left"`

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works with the default configuration of rc.xml.

Comment: Just for clarification, in this case "Left" means _left mouse button_ (not arrow keys), because of the **mousebind** keyword.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about Openbox, but most windows can be dragged by pressing the Alt key and dragging with the mouse anywhere in the window.

Comment: That depends on the window manager configuration. Does Openbox have this configuration by default? [Steven's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/358658) explains how to make Openbox do it.

Comment: @Gilles - I don't know if I have ever used Openbox, but I've used a lot of different window managers and distros, and it seems that most of them had this feature by default.  I'm sure it's not 100% universal, but I thought it was worth a shot here.

Comment: It worked for me on openbox. A window was placed irregularly on the screen and no titlebar was available. Alt + drag worked for me as described in this answer.